# Setting up AWS Route 53 to run Heroku app

Tags: heroku, amazon-aws

I have a domain registered at AWS and an app running on Heroku. I am trying to get AWS Route 53 and DNS records set up correctly without success, and only get the "This site can’t be reached" in the browser.

This is what I have done so far. In Heroku added two custom domains (myappaddress.com replacing my actual domain):

[image]

Then in AWS Route 53 I have created a hosting zone and added a DNS CNAME record as below.

[image]

I have tried all sorts of combinations and followed endless examples but without any success. I wait up to 48 hours after any change I make to the DNS records but the address is still not resolving to my Heroku app.

Is there a definitive guide as to how to set this up correctly?

The images simply show an example of what I am doing and my domain name is not shown. However it illustrates the issues I am having.